# How to sum value of integers based on position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, count

The situation is as followed. I want to sum and eventually calculate their average of specific values based on their positions. So far I have tried many different things and I can come up with the following code, I can't seem to figure out how to match these different positions with their belonging values.

```
    count_pos = 0

    for character in score:
        asci = ord(character)
        count_pos += 1
        print(count_pos,asci)

        if asci == 10 :
           count_pos = 0
```

`print asci` generates the following output:

```
1   35

2   52

3   61

4   68

5   70

6   70




1   35

2   49

3   61

4   68

5   68

6   70
```

The numbers 1-6 are the positions and the other integers are the values belonging to this value. So what I basically am trying to do is to sum the value of position 1 (35+35) which should give me : 70, and the sum of the values of position 2 should give me (52+49) : 101 and this for all positions.

The only thing so far I thought about was comparing the counter like this:

```
    if count_pos == count_pos:
       #Do calculation
```

NOTE: This is just a part of the data. The real data goes on like this with more than 1000 of these counting and not just 2 like displayed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

This would work:

```
from collections import defaultdict

score = '#4=DFF\n#1=DDF\n'
res = defaultdict(int)
for entry in score.splitlines():
    for pos, char in enumerate(entry, 1):
        res[pos] += ord(char)
```

Now:

```
>>> res
defaultdict(int, {1: 70, 2: 101, 3: 122, 4: 136, 5: 138, 6: 140})
>>> res[1]
70
>>> res[2]
101
```

### In Steps

Your score string looks like this (extracted from your asci numbers):

```
score = '#4=DFF\n#1=DDF\n'
```

Instead of looking for `asci == 10`, just split at new line characters with 
the string method `splitlines()`.

The  `defaultdict` from the module `collections` gives you a dictionary that
you can initiate with a function. We use `int()` here. That will call `int()` if we access a key does not exist. So, if you do:

```
res[pos] += ord(char)
```

and the key `pos` does not exit yet, it will call `int()`, which gives a `0`
and you can add your number to it. The next time around, if the number of 
`pos` is already a key in your dictionary, you will get the value and you add
to it, summing up the value for each position.

The `enumerate` here:

```
for pos, char in enumerate(entry, 1):
```

gives you the position in each row named `pos`, starting with `1`.

Comment: It works for so far that it prints two dictionaries with the above values and not with the summed ones ? Is there something I forgot to do like summing the values?

Comment: There is only one dictionary: `res`. Where does the second dictionary come from?

Comment: Note the `+=` here: `res[pos] += ord(char)`. This sums the numbers.

Comment: It shows me two dictionaries  one with the values of the first line of numbers and one of the values of the second line of numbers. I used the += and it still doesn't sum. Maybe it has something to do with the position within the "main" for loop I am using. (This code is pasted inside another for loop)

Comment: You need to do `res = defaultdict(int)` outside of this loop, i.e. at the very beginning.

Comment: The problem here is , that This loop is needed to extract the score from the rest of the lines.. Ill try today thanx !

Answer (score 0):

If you have the two lists to be added in two lists you may do this :

**Using `zip`:**

```
[x + y for x, y in zip(List1, List2)]
```

or

```
zipped_list = zip(List1,List2)
print([sum(item) for item in zipped_list])
```

Eg: If the lists were,

```
List1=[1, 2, 3]
List2=[4, 5, 6]
```

Output would be : `[5, 7, 9]`

**Using Numpy:**

```
import numpy as np
all = [list1,list2,list3 ...]
result = sum(map(np.array, all))
```

Eg:

```
>>> li=[1,3]
>>> li1=[1,3]
>>> li2=[1,3]
>>> li3=[1,3]
>>> import numpy as np
>>> all=[li,li1,li2,li3]
>>> mylist = sum(map(np.array, all))
>>> mylist
array([ 4, 12])
```

Comment: The problem with this is that is just a part of the output. The real data contains several dozen of these outputs with a total length of 102 items per time.

Comment: Why wouldn't this work? It would work fine even for a 102 element list.

Comment: Because there are more than 2 lists.There are a couple 1000 lists

Comment: In that case you may use `numpy`. Shall edit answer.